# How to save a black & white photo as a color photo with Preview App

Tags: macos, photos, preview, color

I open a black & white photo (.jpg) with Preview App (Version 10.1):

[image: B&W Dog]

Then i copy and paste a colored icon:

[image: B&W Dog with rating]

But after saving the picture and open it again the color is missing:

[image: B&W Dog with B&W rating]

Preview annotations such as lines, boxes and colored text added via the Preview app are similarly saved as black and white when re-opened in Finder.

Finder and Preview tell me the image's "Color profile" is set to "Generic Gray Gamma 2.2 Profile" and the "Color space" is "Gray".

I cannot find an easy way how to save this photo (originally saved as b&w) as a color photo with the Preview App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of saving, go `File` > `Export...` and save as a new JPEG.

Comment: Testing in macOS 12.1, `Export` of a B&W image with color Preview annotations also creates a B&W file. Just like `Save`.